# help me with php array sorting

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, trim

I have this array

```
$arr = array('test1', 'test', 'test3', 'var1', 'var5', 'var');
```

and I want to trim/sort the array to be like this

```
$arr = array('test', 'var');
```

Comment: I have to ask - what is the point when you can so easily just make a new array? (unless this is homework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a little vague; it sounds to me like you're asking how to filter out the elements that do not contain a digit, and the provided `$arr` is just an example. In which case you can do the following:

```
$arr = array('test1', 'test', 'test3', 'var1', 'var5', 'var');

function filter($element)
{
  if (ctype_alpha($element)) return $element;
}

$output = array_filter($arr, 'filter');
```

This will also work if your array changes. If you need to sort the results alphabetically, then:

```
natcasesort($output);
```

I could be wrong though; in which case this is slightly overkill.

Comment: You're awesome. I just have another solution but it's longer than your. :-)

Comment: Good eye noticing the `ctype_alpha()` in common

Answer (score 1):

A couple of calls to `array_splice()` will do it, however they cannot be nested because it expects an array reference and will not accept the output of a function call as an input parameter.

```
$arr = array('test1', 'test', 'test3', 'var1', 'var5', 'var');
array_splice($arr, 0, 1);
array_splice($arr, 1, 3);

print_r($arr);
Array
(
    [0] => test
    [1] => var
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $arr = array('test1', 'test', 'test3', 'var1', 'var5', 'var');
 $arr = array($arr[1], $arr[5]);
```

There's a lot of possibilities for variability if the item positions ever move around, but based on what you've posted, I think this is quickest.

Comment: I also like your solution but my programming level is higher than that. :-)

Comment: @Quy - I certainly didn't intend any insult, but your question didn't give very much to go on. We knew what you had and what you wanted. You didn't mention that you were trying to eliminate all values with numbers in them. As a member for all of 5 days, there's no way to know what your programming level is. In future a more specific and detailed question will have a better chance of attracting the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array_unique(array_map('rtrim',$arr,array_fill(1,count($arr),'0123456789')));
```